# asymptotic analysis

Tags: analysis, functions, algorithms

[image: asymptotic analysis]

For each of the following sentences involving functions f and/or g, find a counterexample to show that it is false:
What is meant by counterexamples?

Answer (score 1):

It means that all of the given statements are actually false in general, and the question asks you to find a case (for example via a specific choice for $f$ and $g$) such that the statement is false. For example, for (i), you can pick $f(n) = n$ and $g(n) = \frac{n}{2}$ to see that the implication does not hold.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try that now.